# Origin of the term “pilpul” as a method of Talmudic study

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, words, yeshiva-school

What is the source for referring to the known [method of Talmudic study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilpul) a "pilpul"? When did this usage begin?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38368/what-is-the-pilpul-method-of-learning

Comment: Interesting question. I have to do some digging, but I saw an article that it is related to the word "pilpil" (which I don't think is an "original" Hebrew word) meaning "pepper". It is a metaphor for the "peppery" or "spicy" debating that occurs when two people discuss a Talmudic page.

Comment: What specific information are you looking for that is not in the Wikipedia entry you linked?

Comment: @Alex, the link does not answers/quotes  who was the first to make that conection. It says that Maharal did something like that, but apparently that conection was already in use (?).

Comment: @RenatoGrun "In the narrower sense, pilpul refers to a method of conceptual extrapolation from texts in efforts to reconcile various texts or to explain fundamental differences of approach between various earlier authorities, which became popular in the late fifteenth and early sixteenth centuries: its founders are generally considered to be Jacob Pollak and Shalom Shachna."

Comment: @Alex, so where in Jacob Pollak and Shalom Shachna's writings (are they available?) we see this? A primary source is what i am looking for.

Comment: Maharal was a contemporary of Jacob Pollak and Shalom Shachna. If they were the founders of the method, and Maharal refers to it as pilpul, that is a pretty early source, no?

Comment: Quoting Maharal saying that would qualify as an answer and, perhaps, an earlier source.